# Using initWithNibName changes absolutely nothing

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to load a view controller with a different XIB, but for some unknown reasons it seems that it does not load it at all.

Usually my code is something like this:

```
WorkflowViewController *workflowViewController = [[WorkflowViewController alloc] init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:workflowViewController
                                     animated:YES];
[workflowViewController release];
```

And now I want to load another xib with the same controller so I tried:

```
WorkflowViewController *workflowViewController = [[WorkflowViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Workflow"
                                                                                          bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:workflowViewController
                                     animated:YES];
[workflowViewController release];
```

But it does absolutely nothing! No errors, no warnings, and no xib loaded. Only a blank interface is pushed to the navigation controller :/

Any ideas about why it does so and how to fix it?

Thanks!

- Tom

Comment: Have you actually wired up the view that is in the xib to the view in the controller class?

Comment: I connected the XIB's view to the UIViewController's view property: yes :) I did it in IB. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by creating another controller and another view. Then linked all the stuff back together. It seemed like the views was binded to the controller and nothing was able to change it...

Answer (score 1):

did you try to use nil instead of [NSBundle mainBundle] ?

```
WorkflowViewController *workflowViewController = [[WorkflowViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Workflow" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:workflowViewController
                                 animated:YES];
[workflowViewController release];
```

Comment: I've just did right now and it does the same thing :S Thanks for helping me though :)

Comment: Are you sure your xib is configured correctly? In particular did you set the className WorkflowViewController in the class name of identity inspector in Workflow.xib?

Comment: another hint, could be to "clean" your target to make sure it uses the correct version of your xib... (i hate interface builder)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. My File's Owner is WorkflowViewController, I tried to clean all targets (I hate IB as well hehe). But unfortunately it does not work. I'm starting to think that my navigation controller could be the problem. I'll test some other things out. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and turns out my equivalent of your "WorkFlowViewController" had an empty implementation of "loadView" which wasn't calling super so that