# When do I need to call -[UIViewController initWithNibName:bundle:]?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, designated-initializer

In post [Using initWithNibName changes absolutely nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278312/using-initwithnibname-changes-absolutely-nothing), he shows two uses of the same View Nib definition, in the first case, he simply calls alloc/init and the second, he specifies initWithNibName.

So, while this always works:

`MyViewController *vctrlr = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vctrlr animated:YES];
[vctrlr release];`

The following works for all the View Controllers I've inherited, but not mine!

`TheirViewController *vctrlr = [[TheirViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vctrlr animated:YES];
[vctrlr release];`

New to iOS programming, I inherited some code. All the View Controllers' views are defined in IB, but there was inconsistent allocation/init creation of those view controllers. I created a new View Controller and XIB, but it does not work unless I use initWithNibName (it crashes when I push the view controller onto the Nav Controller). I cannot tell how my view controller is different than the others... any hints? I was able to delete the initNibName usage for all the other view controllers in the app except mine.

Comment: Generally it's good to specify the NIB name as it actually abstracts out the view from the viewcontroller. For example, if you have a controller that has slightly varying views based on some conditions, you can just load in separate nibs as your views.

Comment: Have you implemented the `loadView` method in `vctrlr`?

Comment: `loadViews` are not implemented in either case.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass any string name to `initWithNibName:`. You are not just restricted to calling `initWithNibName:@"MyClassName"` when your class is called `MyClassName`. It could be `initWithNibName:@"MyClassNameAlternateLayout"`.

This becomes useful if you need to load a different nib depending on what the app needs to do. While I try to have one nib per view controller per device category (iPhone or iPad) whenever possible to make development and maintenance simpler, I could understand if a developer would want to provide a different layout or different functionality at times.

Another important point is that [initWithNibName:bundle:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the designated initializer for `UIViewController`. When you call `-[[UIViewController alloc] init]`, then `initWithNibName:bundle:` is called behind the scenes. You can verify this with a symbolic breakpoint. In other words, if you simply want the default behavior, it is expected that you can call `-[[UIViewController alloc] init]` and the designated initializer will be called implicitly.

If, however, you are calling `-[[UIViewController alloc] init]` and not getting the expected behavior, it's likely that your UIViewController subclass has implemented `- (id)init` incorrectly. The implementation should look like one of these two examples:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

or

```
- (id)init
{
    NSString *aNibName = @"WhateverYouWant";
    NSBundle *aBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle]; // or whatever bundle you want
    self = [self initWithNibName:aNibName bundle:aBundle];
    if (self) {
        // custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: +1: I'd also like to add that you *can use the same xib* for different `UIViewController`s. In example, you might have a parent `UIViewController` which has subclasses that have similar (but not the same) functionality using the same set `IBOutlet`s. In this case, you would need to use the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method to specify the parent `xib` file's name.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to work following code:

MyViewController *vctrlr = [[MyViewController alloc] inil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vctrlr animated:YES];

Then you should implement following both methods in MyViewController:

- (id)init
{
   self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
   if (self != nil)
   {
       // Do initialization if needed
   }
   return self;
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)bundle
{
    NSAssert(NO, @"Init with nib");
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: You used method is wrong because using nib file name while creating object of viewcontroller from outside, breaks Encapsulation.